# How to configure and enable SSL in Netezza Database on new port?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, netezza

I want to enable SSL for Netezza DB.

I have generated certificates and Key and placed over "nz/data/secuity" path on my server.

Also configured postgresql.conf file and made

```
ssl=true
server_cert_file='/nz/data/security/server-cert.pem'
server_key_file='/nz/data/security/server-key.pem'
ssl_enabled=true
```

By doing this I have enabled SSL on default port i.e 5480.

But I want to change the port for SSL and configure a new port with SSL enabled.

Comment: IBM support will be able to help.  Have you opened a case with them?

Comment: I have mailed to support@communitysite.ibm.com regarding this, but no reply from them.